# Preserving whitespace / line breaks with REXML

Tags: ruby, xml, whitespace, rexml

I'm using Ruby 1.9.3 and REXML to parse an XML document, make a few changes (additions/subtractions), then re-output the file.  Within this file is a block that looks like this:

```
<someElement>
  some.namespace.something1=somevalue1
  some.namespace.something2=somevalue2
  some.namespace.something3=somevalue3
</someElement>
```

The problem is that after re-writing the file, this block always ends up looking like this:

```
<someElement>
  some.namespace.something1=somevalue1
  some.namespace.something2=somevalue2 some.namespace.something3=somevalue3
</someElement>
```

The newline after the second value (but never the first!) has been lost and turned into a space. Later, some other code which I have no control or influence over will be reading this file and depending on those newlines to properly parse the content. Generally in this situation i'd use a CDATA to preserve the whitespace, but this isn't an option as the code that parses this data later is not expecting one - it's essential that the inner text of this element is preserved exactly as-is.

My read/write code looks like this:

```
xmlFile = File.open(myFile)
contents = xmlFile.read
xmlDoc = REXML::Document.new(contents, { :respect_whitespace => :all })
xmlFile.close

{perform some tasks}

out = ""
xmlDoc.write(out, 2)
File.open(filePath, "w"){|file| file.puts(out)}
```

I'm looking for a way to preserve the whitespace of text between elements when reading/writing a file in this manner using REXML. I've read a number of other questions here on stackoverflow on this subject, but none that quite replicate this scenario. Any ideas or suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get correct behavior by removing the `indent` (second) parameter to `Document.write()`:

```
#xmlDoc.write(out, 2)
xmlDoc.write(out)
```

That seems like a bug in `Document.write()` according to my reading of [the docs](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/rexml/rdoc/REXML/Document.html#method-i-write), but if you don't really need to set the indentation, then leaving that off should solve yor problem.

Comment: I'll give this a shot and report back. Retaining indention would certainly be a plus, though, as I'd like the file to remain easily human-readable if possible.

Comment: It gives you good, readable indentation by default; that option is supposed to override the default, but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: It appears that removing that parameter completely solved the problem. I wish I could remember why I put it in there in the first place. Thanks for your prompt reply.

Comment: You're very welcome.  To clarify my previous statement: it *preserves* the incoming indentation by default, so as long as that is readable and you aren't doing anything too drastic during processing, the output will be readable as well.